# Post previews stopped working on Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

I contacted Linkedin for support on this and they suggested posting here.

I have a website where the Marketing manager would post news items to Linkedin. They used to get a preview of the post before they posted the link. We have noticed that we are unable to get the previews any more.

On the link inspector I get the following message:

**Error We encountered an SSL connection error while trying to access the URL. Please check that the site is using a prime size that is compatible with Java 8, or contact Support with the content's URL.**

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.surelockmcgill.com%2Fnews%2F399-introducing-the-new-gate-locking-range%3Ftest

When looking at posting the link we get the following error:

**Cannot display preview. You can post as is, or try another link.**

I don't seem to be able to find any helpful information so any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards
Mark

Comment: Does anyone from #linkedin have any advice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue the answer was to re-issue our SSL certificate.
There was no initial sign that there was an issue as the website continued to show as secure but there was.

Comment: Question: when you say re-issue do you mean to request a new SSL certificate at the issuer or does it involve sending information to LinkedIn?

Comment: Something happened to the company that issued our SSL which meant we had to re-create the SSL within their system and re-apply it to the website. No LinkedIn involvement necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same problem. I'm also using Cloudflare with the security settings set to most everything. I tried turning the TLS version back to 1.2 and LinkedIn started working. Technically, they say they support 1.3, but it works now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing an answer, you may want to explain why you think your answer is correct, as it may be the case it is not targeting exactly the same problem and the explanation may help to see why

Comment: This worked for me. I reverted the "Minimum TLS Version" to "TLS 1.0 (default)" and turned off "Hotlink protection" to allow LinkedIn to fetch the thumbnail of the link.

Comment: Isn't there a better method (whitelisting etc?) than just turning protections off as suggested?