# Sharing a page to LinkedIn returns an error

Tags: linkedin-api, share

We're having problems with sharing pages to LinkedIn using the URL scheme. Most all URL work fine, but one particular domain fails for every page under it. The response from:

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.robertsellsla.com%2Fcommercial-to-homes

is the immensely helpful "Something went wrong. Refresh the page". No errors in our logs, the page seems to be loading fine. No errors in the console. Per the requirements in LinkedIn, the page should be fine - we have the correct OG tags, the og:image is within their guidelines, but nothing.

Using the Post Inspector tells me that "The URL led to an empty page"m which it obviously does not.  We have many other domains under our system, and they all work fine, but anything under this domain fails the same way.  LinkedIn "help" has told me that, if I can't get a resolution from the Post Inspector, to try a different URL.

All suggestions (other than try a different URL) welcome.

Comment: Where is the error happening? LinkedIn? Your own website? [How do I reproduce this?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Navigating directly to [https://www.robertsellsla.com/commercial-to-homes&&](https://www.robertsellsla.com/commercial-to-homes&&) throws a 404, so it's very possible you're just giving LinkedIn a bad URL.

Comment: My error - somehow the copy added the double-ampersands onto the end. I have corrected my post.

Comment: Sorry - to answer your questions - the error shows up when I use the URL in my post (the LinkedIn share url). That's what gets the "Something went wrong" message. The LinkedIn Post Inspector tells me that the URL "led to an empty page".

Comment: One other thing here - I can share the link via the Facebook, X/Twitter and Pinterest sharing interfaces. Why LinkedIn has it in for this site, I don't know. We even updated the account to a new domain (robertmitchellhomes.com), and still nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you're blocking something at a DNS or website level. I would try (1) [explicitly allowing LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77704871/2535504) in your [robots.txt](https://www.robertmitchellhomes.com/robots.txt) and (2) contacting your vendor, iHOUSEweb, if you haven't already. If you use something like Cloudflare, you might try temporarily disabling that. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts... but I AM the vendor (iHOUSEweb).  We host literally thousands of sites running with their own URLs, and only this one has this problem.  I just wish the Post Inspector gave me some useful information.

Comment: [Here's an idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055004/2535504) I checked a demo site of yours, 1j3lc.ihouseelite.com, and while it's using a different SSL provider, it's using TLS 1.3 and successfully loading in the inspector. The culprit site is using TLS 1.2. I just checked my own site that also uses Let's Encrypt, and it's using TLS 1.3, suggesting you might have an outdated config. Might be something to poke at?

Comment: Dang.. I thought you had it. But here's another of our sites:   https://www.ourhousesold.com/where-does-the-money-come-from-for-mortgage-loans      and it shares fine, even though it's using TLS 1.2. Drat.  Thanks though!

Comment: Cloudflare bot protection and [SSL cert rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63702710/2535504) keep coming up in my searches. You might try rotating your cert just for shits and giggles. The most LinkedIn info I've seen so far is [this article on OG tags](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a521928/), but yours seem fine. A more likely suspect: a ginormous `__PRELOADED_STATE__` JavaScript global. It's causing raw HTML of the site to be 4.8 MB vs ~400 kilobytes on the other working sites. I wouldn't be surprised if that's causing the LinkedIn bot to crash. It's crashing my IDE.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those things.  We might be stuck with the PRELOADED_STATE, React is a hungry beast. But the cert stuff may be a good check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to sheng, I found the problem. Our application builds up a list of links, and hands them off to React. This particular account has a TON of them, and produces a huge page... over which LinkedIn then just throws it's hands up and barfs. So keep an eye on your page sizes when trying to share on LinkedIn.

Too bad their "Post Inspector" wasn't better about diagnosing the problem, this could have been over much earlier.